# Implicit definition of the intersection of n hypersurfaces

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, parametric

This is a follow-up to a question I asked previously.

Let ${F_i(\vec{x}),...,F_n(\vec{x})}$, $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set of hypersurfaces.  I'm particularly interested in the case where $F_i$ is a polynomial.  Assume all $F_i$ are defined such that $F_i(\vec{x}) = 0 \forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Therefore, the $F_i$ are the level sets corresponding to the level 0 for some $n+1$ dimensional hypersurfaces.  I would like to implicitly define their intersection.

If I am looking for a curve that lies entirely within the intersection, then it is known that such a curve will be mutually perpendicular to the gradient of each function.  Under certain conditions, this curve can be defined implicitly as follows:

Let $M = [\bigtriangledown F_1, ..., \bigtriangledown F_n]^T$ and let $\vec{v} \in Null(M)$.  Define the curve implicitly to be:

$$\dot{\xi} = C\vec{v(t)}, \xi(0) = \xi_0$$

Where $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now, can I do something similar to define the hypersurface of intersection implicitly?  Something like a differential equation where I integrate the entire null space?  I apologize for the lack of rigour in that question, but I'm not 100% sure how to approach it.

Comment: If $F_i(\vec{x}) = 0 \ \forall \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $F_i = 0$, and I am sure that this is not what you mean.

Comment: Think of $\Bbb R^2$: if $F_1, F_2$ are polynomials (as you are most interested in), then either $\{F_1 = 0\} \cap \{F_2 = 0\}$ is a *finite* number of points (is this what you want?), or $F_1$ and $F_2$ are proportional and the intersection is $\{F_1 = 0\}$ (again, is this what you want?). Something similar happens if you slightly relax $F_1, F_2$ to be analytic: either they are proportional, or their intersection has no accumulation point (and so is discrete). At least one of the functions must be non-analytic to get something non-trivial.

Comment: In \mathbb{R}^2 you are correct, but in higher dimensions you do in fact get a hypersurface of intersection.  I'd like to know how to implicitly or explicitly define that hypersurface

Comment: In $\Bbb R^n$ take $F_i (\vec x) = x_i$ (they are hyperplanes). Then their intersection is just the point $\vec 0$. This shows that the functions must be chosen carefully; if they *all* are too rigid (analytic, it seems), then the intersection is trivial. The same is true if they are not analytic but they intersect transversally. The problem is much trickier than you believe.

Comment: Those are good points.  In my particular case I actually have a bunch of hyperspheres, hyperplanes, and multilinear functions polynomials that are intersecting, but I'm interested in the general solution.  Is there any good way to start defining the problem better? (Oh, and since your comment does technically count as an answer, if you post it as such I will accept it for the bounty, due to my posting an imprecise question)

Comment: In your specific case the intersection must be quite trivial, since indeed all your examples are polynomial in nature. I feel that my sequence of comments is a bit vague as an answer, so let me see whether my too little spare time will allow come up with something more elaborate - but this won't change the underlying ideas exposed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define the map $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ so that $x \mapsto F(x) = \big(F_1(x), F_2(x), ..., F_m(x)\big)$. You have written that $m=n$, but I would not assume that a priori and for me $m \leq n$. Assume these $F_i(x)$ for $i=1,..., m$ are polynomials in $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with real coefficients, i.e. $F_i \in \mathbb{R}[x_1,...,x_n]$ where $i=1,...,m$. Then, the differential of the map, aka the tangent map to $F$, is $$dF_x = [\nabla F_1(x)^T,..., \nabla F_m(x)^T]^T$$ where $\nabla F_i(x)$ is the gradient of $F_i$ written as a row-vector, so $\nabla F_i(x)^T$ is its transposed (it is a column-vector). Observe $dF_x$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with polynomial coefficients and so it defines the tangent map $$dF_x : T_x\mathbb{R}^n \to T_x\mathbb{R}^m$$ By convention, all tangent vectors are column-vectors and all dual vectors are row-vectors. Assume that $\text{rank}\big(dF_{x_0}\big) = m$, i.e. the rank of $dF_x$ at a point $x_0$ is maximal. Then, generically, the rank of $dF_x$ is maximal for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. In that case,  whenever $m=n$ the inverse mapping theorem (aka the inverse function theorem) applies and then $F$ is a local diffeomorphism and so the solutions to $F(x)=0$ are going to be isolated points. So let us assume that $m < n$.

Now if the rank of $dF_x$ is not $m$ generically, but less than $m$, then you need to run some sort of reduction in the ideal $\langle F_1(x),..., F_m(x) \rangle$  which is the polynomial ideal generated by the polynomials $F_i$. In other words, you need to find a minimal set of generator  $\langle \tilde{F}_1(x),..., \tilde{F}_k(x) \rangle = \langle F_1(x),..., F_m(x) \rangle$ where $k \leq m$. These minimal set of generators is an independent set of polynomials whose matrix of gradients will have rank $k$ generically. Finding the set of of independent generators can be done by running some sort of Groebner basis method or something else of that sort. I advise you to look that up carefully if you need it as I am a bit rusty on the subject. But let us assume that we have done that beforehand, that $k=m$ and that the $F_1, ... ,F_m$ is an independent set of polynomials so that the rank of $dF_x$ is generically $m$.

Next, consider the system $$dF_x (v) = 0 \,\,\, \text{ for } \,\,\, v \in T_x\mathbb{R}^n$$ Now, the tangent field of $n-m$ planes $$\ker(dF)_x = \{v \in T_x\mathbb{R}^n \, | \, dF_x (v) = 0 \}$$ is an integrable distribution of the tangent spaces to the leaves of the foliation $$F^{-1}(y) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, F(x) = y \}$$ Observe you have a system of the form $dF_x(v) = 0$ where the matrix $dF_x$ is a matrix with polynomial coefficients. Thus you can solve the system as a system with polynomial coefficients, i.e. $dF_x$  is an $m \times n$ matrix with coefficients (entries, or elements) in the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{R}[x]$. This ring is a subring of the field of rational functions $\mathbb{R}(x) = \mathbb{R}(x_1,...,x_n)$, where the elements of the latter look like $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ with $P, Q \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Now treat the linear system $dF_x(v_x) = 0$ as a linear system in the field $\mathbb{R}(x) $, since a lot of the linear algebra works in an arbitrary field, you can find a set of $n-m\,\,\ $ $\mathbb{R}(x)$-linearly independent vector-solutions $X_1(x), X_2(x), ... X_{n-m}(x)$, so that each $X_i$ is a vector column of dimension $n$ with rational coefficients (entries that are rational functions of $n$ variables). So if we define $X(x) = [X_1(x),..,X_{n-m}(x)]$, an $n \times (n-m)$ matrix with rational coefficients from  $\mathbb{R}(x)$, then
$$dF_x \, X = 0$$ Just like in the case of equations with integer coefficients, solved in the field of rational numbers, you can even find an appropriate polynomial such that if you multiply all the $X_i$ by it, you end up with $\mathbb{R}(x)$ linearly independent vector-columns $X_1(x), ... , X_{n-m}(x)$ with polynomial coefficients. Thus you have ended up  obtaining a set of polynomial vector fields $X_1(x), ... , X_{n-m}(x)$ that span the distribution $\ker(dF_x)$, i.e. they span the tangent spaces of the leaves of the foliation $F^{-1}(y)$.

These guys $X_1(x), ... , X_{n-m}(x)$ are exactly the analog of what you are referring to in your original posting. If you take the phase flows $x(t_i) = \Phi_i^{t_i}(x)$ of the vector fields $X_i(x)$, then $$\frac{d}{dt_i} \Phi_i^{t_i}(x) = X_i\big(\Phi_i^{t_i}(x)\big), \,\,\,\,\, \Phi_i^{0}(x) = x$$ and then the map $$\Psi_{x_0} \, : \, (t_1, t_2, ..., t_{n-m}) \, \mapsto \,\Phi_1^{t_1} \circ \Phi_2^{t_2} \circ ... \circ \Phi_{n-m}^{t_{n-m}}(x_0)$$ is a local chart for the leaf $M_{x_0} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n  \,\,|\,\,F(x) = F(x_0)\}$ passing through the point $x_0$.

**Edit.** Assume you are given a smooth vector field $X(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then component-wise, it can be written like a vector of $n$ smooth functions (in your case, even polynomial functions), depending on the $n$ vector $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$
$$
X(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \,
    X^1(x_1, ..., x_n)\\
    X^2(x_1, ..., x_n)\\
     \vdots\\
    X^n(x_1, ..., x_n) \,
\end{bmatrix}$$
Each vector field has a family of curves that are tangent to the vector field and through each point in space, there is exactly one such curve passing through that point, which means no two such curves intersect. These are the so called integral curves, also called phase curves, of the vector field $X(x)$. They are obtained as the solutions to the system of ODEs
\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} &= X^1(x_1, ..., x_n)\\
\frac{dx_2}{dt} &= X^2(x_1, ..., x_n)\\
\vdots\\
\frac{dx_n}{dt} &= X^n(x_1, ..., x_n)
\end{align}  which in vector form is written as
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = X(x)$$
Now pick an arbitrary point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and try to solve the initial value problem
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= X(x)\\
x(0) &= x_0
\end{align}
which means you are trying to find a curve $x=x(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is tangent to the vector field $X(s)$ and passes through the point $x_0$, i.e.
$$\frac{dx}{dt}(t) = X\big(x(t)\big) \,\,\, \text{ for all } \,\, t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) $$ and $x(0) = x_0$. By the classical theorems of ODEs, there exists exactly one such curve (existence and uniqueness of solutions of systems of smooth ODEs). Now, denote by $$x(t) = \Phi^t(x_0
)$$ for $t \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ this curve, a notation which says that the curve depends on the parameter $t$ and on the initial condition $x_0$. When I change $t$, I move along the curve, but when I change $x_0$ I move from one curve tangent to the vector field $X$ to another. So technically we have a map 
$$\Phi \, : \, (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times \mathbb{R}^n \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^n$$ By another result of ODE theory, this map is a smooth map (in your case it is even real analytic, because your vector field is polynomial, which means real analytic). If you fix the parameter $t$, you get a diffeomorphism (bijection, smooth in both directions) 
$$\Phi^t \, : \,  \mathbb{R}^n \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^n$$ It is a bijection because of the existence and uniqueness result for ODEs. For a fixed $x_0$ what you have is that 
$$\frac{d}{dt} \Phi^t(x_0) = X\big(\Phi^t(x_0)\big)$$ 
$$\Phi^0(x_0) = x_0$$ This map $\Phi$ is called the phase flow map (or simply the phase flow) of the vector field. Again due to the existence  and uniqueness of solutions of smooth ODEs, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any $t, s \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ the phase flow has the properties
$$\Phi^t\Big(\Phi^s(x)\Big) = \Phi^{t+s}(x)$$
$$\Phi^0(x) = x$$ In your case you have a (family of) $n-m$ hypersurface $F^{-1}(y_0) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, F(x) = y_0\}$ where $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, which basically says that $x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in F^{-1}(y_0)$ if and only if
\begin{align}
&F_1(x_1, ..., x_n) = y_{1,0}\\
&F_2(x_1, ..., x_n) = y_{2,0}\\
& \,\,\,\, \vdots \\
&F_m(x_1, ..., x_n) = y_{m,0}\\
\end{align}
Moreover, you have $n-m$ such vector fields $X_1, ..., X_{n-m}$ all tangent to $F^{-1}(y_0)$. This means that you have $n-m$ phase flow maps $\Phi_1^{t_1}, ...., \Phi_{n-m}^{t_{n-m}}$ for depending on $n-m$ different independent parameters $(t_1, t_2,..., t_{n-m}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n-m}$. The fact that the vector fields are tangent is equivalent to the fact that for each $j = 1,...,n-m$
$$F\big(\Phi_j^{t_j}(x)\big) = F(x)$$ or in coordinates
$$F_i\big(\Phi_j^{t_j}(x)\big) = F_i(x)$$ for $i=1,..., m$.
If you compose the maps $$\Phi^{t_j}_j \, : \, \mathbb{R}^n \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^n$$ for $j=1,...,n-m$ you get again a map
$$\Psi(t_1,...,t_{n-m},x) = \Phi^{t_1}_1\Big(...\Phi^{t_{n-m}}_{n-m}(x)\Big) = \Phi^{t_1}_1\circ ... \circ\Phi^{t_{n-m}}_{n-m}(x)$$ where $$\Psi \, : \, \mathbb{R}^{n-m} \times \mathbb{R}^n \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^n$$ with the property that $$F\Big(\Psi(t_1,...,t_{n-m},x)\Big) = F\Big(\Phi^{t_1}_1\big(...\Phi^{t_{n-m}}_{n-m}(x)\big)\Big) = F\Big(\Phi^{t_1}_1\circ ... \circ\Phi^{t_{n-m}}_{n-m}(x)\Big) = F(x)$$ so if you fix a point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ on the surface $F(x) = y_0$, meaning $F(x_0) = y_0$, you obtain a map
$$\Psi_{x_0}(t_1,...,t_{n-m}) = \Psi(t_1,...,t_{n-m},x_0)= \Phi^{t_1}_1\Big(...\Phi^{t_{n-m}}_{n-m}(x_0)\Big) = \Phi^{t_1}_1\circ ... \circ\Phi^{t_{n-m}}_{n-m}(x_0)$$ where $$\Psi_{x_0} \, : \, \mathbb{R}^{n-m} \, \to \, \mathbb{R}^n$$
which parametrizes the $n-m$ hypersurface $F(x) = y_0$.

Comment: This is fantastic and gives me a lot to go on, thanks.  A brief question: although I'm interested in polynomials only, I wonder if there are any differences between doing this in polynomials and doing it in general?  Your solution relied on the fact that the system was a system of polynomials (which really helps me).  I assume that in general you'd need stricter requirements on, say, the gradients to ensure that they are independent?

Comment: I hope what I wrote helps you a little bit. In general, when the functions $F_i$ are not polynomial, basically everything is the same. Whenever the rank of $dF_x$ is maximal at a point $x$, it is maximal in a neighborhood of $x$. If you check that the rank $dF_x$ is maximal for every point $x$ such taht $F(x)=0$, then the latter is a submanifold and everything I said goes through. The only thing is finding the vector fields $X_1,..,X_m$ explicitly. They are there, just I am not sure about a structured procedure on how to find them. But again, I didn't think about it enough.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the procedure for finding the vector fields for polynomial systems is well known, but that in general the procedure for doing so may not be as well known? (I'm just trying to justify a step I did where I turned a non polynomial system into a polynomial one.  Of course, if there is no such justification then I guess I can always go back on that step :-) )

Comment: In the polynomial case you have the advantage of being able to write a procedure on a computer that will be able to compute the $X$'s. Possibly the same procedure that solves a system of linear equations with integer coefficients, copied line for line, but operating with polynomials (and rational functions) instead of integers and rational numbers. In the non-polynomial case... the existence of the $X$'s is guaranteed (as long as the rank of $dF_x$ is maximal). Without a general recipe as structured as the polynomial case.

Comment: Great, that is very helpful.  Since I was looking at the nonlinear equations and realized that by transforming them into a better understood form would help, I'm glad that it seems that step was a good one.  It's possible that the original equations have a "nice" solution, but I was unable to find it until I turned them into polynomials

Comment: Wait, so your original problem is not polynomial in nature, you just approximate your $F$'s by polynomials, is that it? You know, do you have a specific problem in mind, because for instance in symplectic geometry, if $n=2m$ then you have a symplectic duality, which turns each differential $dF_i$ into a vector field $X_i$ tangent to the hypersurface $F_i(x)=0$. So no need to solve systems here, the vector fields come for free. And it is general, no polynomials are necessary. Is in your original system $n=2m$ by any chance?

Comment: The original equations are non polynomial, but I was able to use a change of variables to turn into a system of constrained polynomials.  The actual problem is to determine the forces and torques acting on a point due to forces and torques applied at multiple points (well, it's more complex, but it's hard to write it into a comment on stack exchange).  However, turning into the polynomials provided one other result that was, as far as I can tell, not possible with the original equations.  One day I'll look at the originals and see what can be done, perhaps...

Comment: I should also mention that moving into the system of polynomials was just intellectually more fun, since I got to learn about algebraic geometry as I went :-)

Comment: Ok, so if the polynomials are obtained by a change of variables, then that's a good thing. Then staying with the polynomials is better for computational purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're still follow this, but I had one more question.  Why is $F_x0$, which I have assumed is the local function that encodes the object I'm looking for, made up of the composition of the $\Phi$ functions?  Or is that another operation?

Comment: Since a vector field $X_i$ is tangent to the $n-m$ submanifold $F^{-1}(y_0) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, F(x) = y_0\}$ for any $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then it is in particular tangent to each $n-1$ submanifold $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \, : \, F_j(x) = c_0\}$. This is equivalent to saying that $F_j\big(\Phi^{t_i}_i(x)\big) = F_j(x)$ for any $j=1,..,m$, i.e. $F_j$ is a first integral (constant of motion) of $X_j$. This means that $F\big(\Phi^{t_i}_i(x)\big) = F(x)$, i.e. each trajectory  $\Phi_i^{t_i}(x)$ starting on $F^{-1}(y_0)$ stays  on $F^{-1}(y_0)$.

Comment: Since the vector fields $X_i$ are linearly independent at each point of $F^{-1}(y_0)$, then their trajectories are transverse to each other (go in  different directions) and you end up having a curvylinear coordinate net on  $F^{-1}(y_0)$ given by $F_{x_0}(t_1,..,t_{n-m}) = \Phi_1^{t_1} \circ ... \circ \Phi_{n-m}^{t_{n-m}}(x_0)$.

Comment: I recognize that this thread is now over a month old, but I am still not clear on the composition operation.  If I understand it, $f \circ g(x)$ is a 1 dimensional function, $f(g(x))$.  However, you answer seemed to imply that we get a hypersurface.  Did I misinterpret the operation?

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Read my edit to the original  answer. Maybe you got mixed up because I abused some notation at the end by writing the new map as $F_{x_0}$. Now I've changed its notation to $\Psi_{x_0}$ and have added explanations about phase flows and vector fields.

Comment: It's more clear now, thanks.  I think I have some studying to do :-)